# WolframAlpha ImageIdentify API

Tags: image-processing, wolframalpha

I need to run queries to https://www.imageidentify.com/ from my own program (written in Python, but it shouldn't matter as there appears to be no any package that works with WolframAlpha). I've found WolframAlpha Webservice API Reference, but I don't think that it can help me with ImageIdentify.

WolframAlfa support ImageIdentify language symbol in its Wolfram Language, but I don't see how I can use it via API, especially when ImageIdentify obviously needs to use a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be impossible to do via public API, however it can be done using standalone WolframAlpha installation - just write a script that uses ImageIdentify function and feed it to MathematicaScript.